# Division symbol in welding proceedure

Tags: welding

I am dealing with a European contractor, and often I see a division symbol (÷) in their documents, screenshot below. Could somebody explain what that means? P.S. Hope this is the right stack for it. If not, kindly suggest where to post it instead.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of welding proceedure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in Polish , which the above is written in , the division sign is sometimes used to denote a range of values. [source](https://academic-accelerator.com/encyclopedia/division-sign)

Comment: Thanks for the source too!

Answer (score 1):

Without any other info, I would suggest that they mean + or - 2mm on the stated dimension.

If you gave more info then that would help confirm my conclusion.

Comment: It seems that in Polish , which the above is written in , the division sign is sometimes used to denote a range of values.

Comment: @SamiSafarini, yes, you are correct! If only you could post an answer I will close this question. 
I had a chat with our Polish vendor and it’s true, in Poland they use division symbol as a range.